# Merge two datasets duplicate BY variables Or I want to make following form

Tags: merge, sas

I am a novice in SAS program.
I have a question about merging two dataset.

The two data sets look like (please click this Image link (Excel sheet image):

[image]

Please let me know key concepts or code to make this happen!
I have searched the answer through Googling etc., but there is no site that exactly solve what I want.

(If it is possible to tackle above question without PROC SQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired result you should do a cartesian product (Cross join) which returns all the rows in all tables. Each row in table1 is paired with all the rows in table2. I have used `Proc SQL` to do this and I am eager to see how this can be done using `Data step`. Here's what I know,

```
Proc Sql;
create table test_merge as 
select a.*, b.type_rhs, b.rhs1, b.rhs2
from test a, test11 b 
where a.yearmonth=b.yearmonth
;
quit;
```

Again, I am new to SAS as well and I think this is one of the ways to create the desired output.

When working with huge data, you will see a note in log that says "The execution of this query involves performing one or more Cartesian product joins that can not be optimized."